# Run python script everyday to open and execute a program

Tags: python

Is it possible for a python script to open and execute a program each day at a specific time? My attention is...poor, but I installed a productivity program (FocalFilter) which blocks unproductive websites. Could a python script be written where it opens this program and runs it so the sites are blocked as soon as I get to my computer in the morning?

Does it matter if the computer is in locked mode (Windows 10)? I don't need a script or anything, it can be a fun little project, but I just don't know if it is even possible.

Comment: You can use scheduled jobs to run programs at specific times. Your computer will need to be left running for this to work though, or you could use a virtual cloud to do this such as AWS.

Comment: It is possible.  Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should also spend time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), it will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problems.

Comment: AWS Lambda will let you do this in cloud: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed you can use python. But the operating system(s) do it for you now.
Scheduled tasks run even if the computer is locked. 
Take look at this:
https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html
or look att the Scheduler in Administration tools in Control panel. There you have many cool options.

Also, if you permanently want to block certain sites, like facebook.com and stackoverflow.com you can edit your hosts file so that facebook.com goes to 127.0.0.1, i.e. your own computer. Antiviruses do this too. Read here:
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/